# Java script вывод информации при клике по объекту

Tags: javascript

назрел такой вопрос, разрабатываю сайт
Сделал через Json интерактивную карту , при наведении идет подсветка ее , в Json все координаты регионов России записаны от 1 до 85 id , вопрос заключается в том как мне при клике условно по 14 региону вывести Информацию хотя бы где-то сбоку , как именно нужно привязаться к id Json через JS чтобы потом на сайте когда я сделал клик вывелась какая-то информация?
Как пример на сайте https://stats.hh.ru/map ,я навожусь на регион и кликая по нему он выдает мне краткую сводную информацию , как мне сделать также?
Код карты у меня в таком формате , карта формируется в Json

```
viewPort": "-65 0 1134 620",
  "regions": [{
    "ident": "91",
    "name": "\u0420\u0435\u0441\u043f\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0438\u043a\u0430 \u041a\u0440\u044b\u043c",
    "paths": ["M-4.782,433.757L-1.546,433.757L-0.00099999999999767,434.847L2.011,435.12L2.011,433.985L3.763,433.757L4.832,435.453L9.205,435.453L9.325,433.985L10.895,434.322L10.895,437.118L12.686,438.877L11.618,441.452L13.691,443.619L13.69 и так далее
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Тебе надо SVG карту, на элементы в svg вешай onclick и делать что хочешь

Comment: У меня код в Json , карта без svg , код такого формата                                                                                           viewPort": "-65 0 1134 620",
  "regions": [{
    "ident": "91",
    "name": "\u0420\u0435\u0441\u043f\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0438\u043a\u0430 \u041a\u0440\u044b\u043c",
    "paths":

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]